# Interactive animations on Android

Tags: android, animation, 3d

This may be a duplicate question, but none of the questions I found were exactly what I had in mind.

A friend and I want to create an App that lets the user play around with 3D objects on the screen. My friend is creating the objects and the animations in Blender or Maya. Therefore, the possible animations will be preset (not being programmatically animated). I have no experience in 3D programming and I naively suggested that he render the animations in Blender and send me all the frames. I would then play the appropriate animation by quickly running through all the frames. Each animation would leave the object in its original position so that it would be ready for the next animation.

Now that I've been thinking about it, that's a lot of images that I have to store in order to make this work. For every object, I would need to have all its frames for all of its animations, which maybe overkill.

Is there another way to play animations in an Android app? I considered just saving the animations as videos and playing them, but that would look horrible for our purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest [min3D](https://code.google.com/p/min3d/)

Take a look at the [animated troll](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=min3d.sampleProject1) example they have.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of 3D libraries for Android. I would recommend AndEngine. Alternatively, you can just use the native OpenGL compatibility. Instead, ask him to send you the actual 3D files. Then you can use a library to render them.

EDIT: I just found [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) link. It'll probably help you. In my opinion, you should go through it and learn the whole package instead of just glancing a bit for this one little project; it'll help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way you can manupulate the models you created in Blender. here is an example which uses Open GL in android to animate a 3D model created in Blender [Check This Video Out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xvauTco_Vs). However it animates the object programatically, frame animation is indeed not worth if you wanna create animations that are long as you will run out of memory quick.